# Как показать нужный блок под картой leaflet по клику на слой?

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Есть карта аналогичная [примеру](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html). В коде есть функция зума, вызываемая при клике на регион

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}
```

Как дополнить функцию, чтобы при клике не только выполнялся зум, но и под самой картой из спрятанных n дивов, отображался необходимый, соответствующий id региона. `id` региона извлекается из [файла](http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js)

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Не понятно что именно у вас не получается

Comment: @ConstantinePl переформулировал

Comment: По прежнему не совсем понятно что именно не получается. 

есть функция function zoomToFeature(e). e.feature.id я так понимаю содержит ИД сущности по которой кликнули. 

Вам остается дополнить эту функцию своим функционалом который делает все что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Все же нашел сам решение, если кому-то в будущем понадобится, то сделал так:

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    var layer = e.target;
    var alldb = document.getElementsByClassName('region-info');
    for(var i = 0; i < alldb.length; i = i + 1) {
            alldb[i].style.display="none";
    }           
    var el = document.getElementById('region-' + layer.feature.properties.cartodb_id);          
    el.style.display = "block";
}
```

где `region-info` - класс всех блоков с информацией к каждому региону;
`layer.feature.properties.cartodb_id` - `id` региона на карте из файла для карты.